# Pandas: create columns with tuples as labels from unique pairs of row values

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a df like this:

| timestamp | data_point_1 | data_point_2 | some_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/06/24 | a | b | 2 |
| 2021/06/24 | c | d | 3 |
| 2021/06/25 | c | d | 3 |

I want to change it to a df like this, that has tuples of unique value pairs of column `data_point1` and `data_point2` and only have the `some_data` column value for each `timestamp`:

| timestamp | (a,b) | (c,d) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/06/24 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021/06/25 | NaN | 3 |

Here's the example data snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ["2021/06/24", "2021/06/24", "2021/06/25"], 'data_point_1': ["a", "c", "c"], 'data_point_2': ["b", "d", "d"], 'some_data': [2, 3, 3]})

print(test)
#    timestamp data_point_1 data_point_2  some_data
# 0  2021/06/24            a            b          2
# 1  2021/06/24            c            d          3
# 2  2021/06/25            c            d          3

# desired:
#    timestamp   (a,b)       (c,d)
# 0  2021/06/24    2           3
# 1  2021/06/25    0           3
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with convert `MultiIndex` values to tuples:

```
df = test.pivot('timestamp', ['data_point_1','data_point_2'], 'some_data')
df.columns = [tuple(x) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    timestamp  (a, b)  (c, d)
0  2021/06/24     2.0     3.0
1  2021/06/25     NaN     3.0
```

If need aggregate values, it means there are duplicates per `timestamp, data_point_1, data_point_2` use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function like `mean`:

```
#if need aggregate values
#df = test.pivot_table(index='timestamp', 
                       columns=['data_point_1','data_point_2'], 
                       values='some_data', 
                       aggfunc='mean')
df.columns = [tuple(x) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: You're so fast. Thanks for the answer, I really enjoy your answers and admire your proficiency. Ďakujem!

Comment: @mneumann - You are welcome! Rado sa stalo!